# Empty value in attribute | Plugin CRM C#

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I change only 1 field in the interface - "telephone1", and leave the second one unchanged, in the end I want field 3 to contain both 1 changed field and 2 field unchanged, but for some reason it is empty, although it contains values, it also works and vice versa. "InputParametres" as I understand it is a bad idea, but what other options are there?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUdLn.png

```
 if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            try
            {
                var createReq = new CreateRequest() { Parameters = context.InputParameters };
                var res = createReq.Target; // Has type Entity
                
                // Получить целевой объект из входных параметров
                Entity entityInput = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                // entityInput.Attributes["telephone3"] = entityInput. + ";" + entityInput.Attributes["telephone2"];
                entityInput.Attributes["telephone3"] = res.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone1") + ";" + res.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone2");

               // service.Update(entityInput);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error in update telephone3 - {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException($"Плагин {nameof(Class1)} был зарегистрирован неправильно");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Target` will have only changed attributes and it’s values. If you need the values from unchanged attributes (fields) you have to use `PreImage` to consume them.

You can register `PreImage` in Plug-in registration tool similar to steps, filtering attributes, etc.

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/thinkdynamicdodynamic/posts/pre-image-and-post-image-in-dynamics-crm)

Comment: Agree, in order for your plugin to know what was there before, you need to pass the preImage of the entity to know the value before your update.